# How to select the other vertices/edges after rip/rip fill

Tags: mesh

If I select vertices or edges and use rip (same for rip fill) Blender creates copies of them and choses one set which is then selected and can be translated. How do I select the other set instead?

Example: Select one edge of standard cube:

[image: Standard cube]

After rip and some translation it is obvious that the edge belonging to top face was chosen:

[image: Ripped standard cube]

How to select the edge belonging to front face instead (without performing a translation and for more complicated meshes of course)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place the mouse on the wanted side :

[image]